# Restore sqlite3 on Mac OS X for Google Chrome

Tags: osx-snow-leopard, google-chrome, sqlite

I was stupid enough to compile `sqlite3` from source and install it to `/usr`, overriding default library.
This being done, Google Chrome doesn't launch anymore, crashing with this output:

```
Dyld Error Message:
  Library not loaded: /usr/lib/libsqlite3.dylib
  Referenced from: /System/Library/Frameworks/Security.framework/Versions/A/Security
  Reason: no suitable image found.  Did find:
    /usr/lib/libsqlite3.dylib: mach-o, but wrong architecture
    /usr/local/lib/libsqlite3.dylib: mach-o, but wrong architecture
    /usr/lib/libsqlite3.dylib: mach-o, but wrong architecture
```

Can I somehow revert `sqlite3` to the original version I had, or fix the issue somehow else?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was able to fix that by compiling `sqlite3` for `i386` and `x86_64` and placing it in `/usr`:

```
./configure --prefix=/usr --disable-dependency-tracking CFLAGS="-arch i386 -arch x86_64"
```

Answer (score 1):

On my system, libsqlite3.dylib was installed as part of the BaseSystem package, and updated by the 10.6.5 and 10.6.7 packages.

```
$ grep -rl libsqlite3.dylib /var/db/receipts/
/var/db/receipts/com.apple.pkg.BaseSystem.bom
/var/db/receipts/com.apple.pkg.update.os.10.6.5.patch.bom
/var/db/receipts/com.apple.pkg.update.os.10.6.7.patch.bom
```

You can extract just those files from the original .pkg files using something like [Pacifist](http://www.charlessoft.com/), [pkgutil](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/pkgutil.1.html) or [installer](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man8/installer.8.html). It wasn't immediately obvious to me how to extract a single file from a .pkg file with the command line tools. It's pretty straightforward with Pacifist; [docs are here](http://www.charlessoft.com/Pacifist_Documentation/English/index.html).

Answer (score 0):

If you changed soemthing in /usr you have changed code provided by Apple so you will have to reinstall the OS. However as this is a large chnage I would try first restoring mysql from your backup :). If not then get the combo OSX verstion update from [Apple](http://support.apple.com/kb/dl1349). Otherwise go to the OSX DVD you can restore a few files by looking at the package contents - however my OSX is messed up and and don't have the correct package name.

For this particular case you could recompile as @gaearon says but you have to get the correct version and assume Apple have done no changes.

In general I would add new libraries using a package manager fink, macports etc. as they place things outside Apple system areas and deal with any oddities of OSX. If you compile your own use /usr/local

Comment: It's a standard library so there is no point for Apple to make changes to it. It's used by a lot of non-system applications, e.g. Chrome and Firefox. The problem was not in version, rather in that I compiled it only for `x86_64` arch, whereas it should've been compiled both for `i386` and `x86_64`, or else half the applications stops working. Luckily, all apps work well enough with the new version—and next time I'll install my stuff in `/usr/local`. Thanks for your note!

Comment: I agree in this case but Apple can  make changes to Open Source software e.g. to use their Frameworks and then having side effects.